# Least square solution to $AXB+CXD=E$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, matrix-equations, quadratic-programming, least-squares

I am trying to find the least-squares solution $X$ of the following matrix equation

$$AXB+CXD=E$$

Of course, I know that this equation can be written in the form

$$(B^T \otimes A+D^T \otimes C) \operatorname{vec} X = \operatorname{vec} E$$

where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, and we can take the pseudoinverse of the Kronecker product matrix on the LHS to get $X$. However, I wonder whether we can get the answer in terms of the pseudoinverses $A^{+}$, $B^{+}$, $C^{+}$ and $D^{+}$? I know that if we want to find the least-squares solution of $AXB=E$, we have a solution $X=A^{+}EB^{+}$. Can we write in a similar way a solution of the more complicated case? Thanks!

Comment: Are the coefficient matrices square?

Answer (score 4):

This is the [Sylvester equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) A simple explicit solution is possible under certain conditions (no common eigenvalues of the matrices $C^{-1}A$ and $-DB^{-1}$), as explained in the Wikipedia page. There are more complicated general methods, see

1. [The explicit solution of the matrix equation $AX−XB=C$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02466983) (1995)
2. [Continued-fraction solution of matrix equation $AX-XB=C$](http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTotal-JAXG198909000.htm)(1989)
3. [Explicit
   solutions of the matrix equation $AX−XB=C$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02843670) (1974)
4. [Explicit Solutions of Linear Matrix Equations](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1012104) (1970)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because I am studying a low-rank solution to this equation, and it's hard to deal with the rank when it is in vectorization form. I will look at these papers.